# Set the size of imsave() image output

Tags: matplotlib

I have array with shape 15x30, and want to save it as pseudocolor plot with `imsave()` in pylab mode. However the size of the output image produced is 15x30px. I tried setting dpi parameter, but it doesn't help nor this function have any other parameter that will change the image size.

So how can I save pseudocolor image from array, with `imsave()` and change the size of output image?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=imsave#matplotlib.pyplot.imsave  If you note the documentation says that 'The DPI to store in the metadata of the file. This does not affect the resolution of the output image.'

Comment: @tcaswell: Instead 15x30 I want to output image to 150x300px size, so that instead one pixel per array value I get 10x10px per array value, just like it's displayed in plot window if I use `pcolor()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really hacky solution to this to just scale up your data:

```
data = rand(10, 15)
new_data = np.zeros(np.array(data.shape) * 10)

for j in range(data.shape[0]):
    for k in range(data.shape[1]):
        new_data[j * 10: (j+1) * 10, k * 10: (k+1) * 10] = data[j, k]

imsave(new_data)
```

Comment: :) I hope(d) there is easier way, without reshaping

Comment: you might want to dig in to PIL, or just use imagemagik after it has been saved.

Comment: That's a good idea. Here is PIL oneliner: `Image.fromarray(data).convert('RGB').resize((150, 300)).save('data.png')`

Comment: @theta You should post that as an answer.

Comment: It's easily visible as comment too, plus `.convert('RGB')` doesn't seem to convert image from gray to RGB, so it's not complete yet. I picked that RGB conversion from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711880/pil-using-fromarray-with-binary-data-and-writing-coloured-text

Comment: there is a much lower threshold for comments getting deleted, you should not consider them permanent. You can color map your data with out using `imshow` or `imsave` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488188/matplotlib-save-imshow-array/14488890#14488890

Comment: I guess data needs to be reshaped again. If I resize with PIL and use `imshow(data, cmap='hot')` I still get gray image. If you can do it, post it, I'll upvote :)